# My CkEditor not looking good in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

My CkEditor look like see image

[image]

Can you help me please...
I want to display ckeditor like on  http://ckeditor.com/demo

This issue is in active admin. I want to use ckeditor on active admin.
My Active Admin version is = 0.6.0

Comment: I still face the same issue today

Comment: its working in chrome for me now - http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/rails-user-modifies-email/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is related to a change in Active Admin CSS style described in this issue:
 https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1852

There is also a pull request awaiting merging: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/1952

For *temporary* fix i'm using my cloned version with this diff applied:

```
gem 'activeadmin', :git => "git@github.com:kars7e/active_admin.git"
```

The offending CSS is the reset style which unfortunately has higher importance than CKEditor styles.

**EDIT:**

The maintainers of original repo have merged the fix and it's working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

probably something is missing, try inspect element( chrome browser) and reload the page,see if there is some error where something is not loaded because you got the thing, just styling is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, code in following wiki page helped a little....

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Ckeditor-integration

Answer (score 0):

You can use this fix: https://gist.github.com/SebAshton/4690552 (it worked well for me)